# Which approach to use to unit-test this component ? Sociable vs solitary?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to implement a feature that extracts a Zip subfolder into a folder. A candidate interface could be (Java):

```
interface ZipExtractor {
    void extract(File zipFile, String subfolderName, File targetFolder);
}
```

As I intend to implement this interface, I will have two related sub-components: a class that is able to list the files in a zip subfolder, and a class that can extract a single file from a zip.

I googled a lot for best practices in this case and have found some interesting debates like :

- solitary vs sociable unit tests
- mockist vs classic style
- "file system access should always be mocked" vs "it's OK while test suite run time is not much impacted"

What is the best choice :

- using ZipExtractor as is, give it a real file existing on the file system, and check that files are correctly extracted ? It sounds more like a mini-integration test but the code is smaller and simpler and I test the whole feature.
- mock the subcomponents of ZipExtractor to return a fake list of subfiles and not write on the file system, and also add tests on subcomponents ? This is real unit testing but needs some more config from tests so the code is more verbose.

My personal feeling would be to use the first approach, but I want other opinions with arguments. Thanks

Comment: I'd do both.  Every project needs unit and integration tests.  It need not be an either/or choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here, unitary testing means asserting a series of method invocations.
You will mock a lot of things and finally you will not be able to check a real useful thing for the use case. You will mainly check that methods are called. 
.

It is a little like asserting that a SQL query is executed.
It is helpless. What we want here is either checking the result from the query or mocking the service that performs the query.
You will never mock connection, query, statement, etc...

Unitary tests have great value when there is have some logic to test : computations, transformations, etc...
Here the great value is performed when you extract a folder from a zip to a target folder.
 
So like you I would prefer the first way :

> using ZipExtractor as is, give it a real file existing on the file
>   system, and check that files are correctly extracted ? It sounds more
>   like a mini-integration test but the code is smaller and simpler and I
>   test the whole feature.

At last, tests have to be maintained and creating tests without added value is often a sin because these are often not maintained or bad maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you like the sound of "unit-testing a component", but don't really like the idea of unit-testing a component. So you would like someone to give you a blessing to do an integration test, but still call it a "unit test".

This is much like like asking if it's all right to make a veggie-burger with real meat, because it tastes much better.  But still insist on calling it a "veggie-burger", because it sounds nicer.

Bottom line: go ahead and use a real file system. Just don't call it a unit test. Unless you really like the sound of it and your colleagues agree, then you can call it an "application server" or a "cat", or a "toothbrush".

Answer (score 0):

> using ZipExtractor as is, give it a real file existing on the file system, and check that files are correctly extracted

This is perfectly fine. The unit under test, the thing you want to prove works correctly, is the extraction of the subfolder from the zip archive. So, in this case, you successfully test the unit of extracting from the archive, despite relying on other units.

Naturally, this means that a bug in another unit can cause this test to fail, despite the unit you want to test working correctly. To ensure that you can identify the real problem domain in the case of a failure, an additional test for the class that lists the files in the archive would probably be a good idea, too.

> ... It sounds more like a mini-integration test but the code is smaller and simpler and I test the whole feature.

There are different schools of thought on this. Martin Fowler, [writes this](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) on the subject (my own emphasis added):

> Indeed using sociable unit tests was one of the reasons we were criticized for our use of the term "unit testing". I think that the term "unit testing" is appropriate because these tests are tests of the behavior of a single unit. **We write the tests assuming everything other than that unit is working correctly**.

In more complex cases, however, a mock may be more appropriate for an external resource like a filesystem. It's something I feel should be considered on a case-by-case basis. On this, Martin Fowler writes

> If talking to the resource is stable and fast enough for you then there's no reason not to do it in your unit tests.

In this case, making sure your zip file is present, has correct permissions, etc should be pretty stable. So, I say there's no reason you should not be able to use the zipfile and filesystem as part of your unit test.

Though, it sounds like you may have already read these discussions. As you've probably determined it really depends who you ask. My biggest fear for writing the test the way you describe would not be whether or not the code is tested properly, but rather that someone will beat me over the head with their rule book because their idea of a unit test is different than mine.